# Adding additional vertical lines to start of row adds padding to table border

Tags: tables, longtable

I'm trying to create a table using `longtblr` (as it will eventually span multiple pages) such that some rows may be compound rows. That is, multiple subsequent rows are all considered a single grouped item.

Initially, I thought to use row highlights but that didn't seem obvious enough. Same when I tried `hline`s. Then I thought I could use a double `vline` (I tried a double `hline` but that seems to separate the rows from the rest of the table entirely). However, when I do this, it essentially adds the second vline to the left instead of right, thus pushing the table's border oddly out such that only the grouped row is connected.

I've seen other solutions use `multicolumn` with the column specification to include additional vline, however, this triggers an error as `longtblr` no longer supports the old interface.

Here's what I have and what I it creates:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{newpxtext,eulerpx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{row{1} = {bg=black, fg=white, font=\sffamily},colspec = {|X[1.25,c]X[1,c]X[0.75,l]c|},width = 1.0\linewidth,caption={},rowhead=1, rowfoot=1}
  Type & Name & Attributes & Number\\
  \SetRow{lightgray}
  TypeA & NameA & {AttributeA.1 \\ AttributeA.2} & {\SetCell{fg=yellow}3} \\
  \SetRow{white}
  TypeF & NameF & {AttributeF.1 \\ AttributeF.2} & \SetCell{fg=red}5 \\
  \SetRow{lightgray}
  TypeG & NameG & {AttributeG.1 \\ AttributeG.2} & \SetCell{fg=red}5 \\
  \SetRow{white}
  TypeH & NameH & {AttributeH.1 \\ AttributeH.2} & \SetCell{fg=red}5 \\
  \hline
  %grouped items, 2 rows
  \SetVline[1]{6-7}{1pt}
  \SetVline[2]{6-7}{1pt}
  \SetRow{lightgray}
  TypeC & NameC & {AttributeC.1 \\ AttributeC.2} & \SetCell{fg=red}5 \\
  \SetRow{lightgray}
  TypeD & NameD & {AttributeD.1 \\ AttributeD.2} & \\
  \hline
  \SetRow{white}
  TypeE & NameE & {AttributeE.1 \\ AttributeE.2} & {\SetCell{fg=purple}4} \\
  \hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: multiple vline error]

How do I push the second vline to the right inside the cell instead of the left along with the outer border? Alternatively, is there another way to create this *or* another way to indicate grouped rows?

EDIT: This is a crudely drawn edit of what I tried. Notice how the outer table border is as normal for the `colspec` and the additional row border is to the right, within the outer border.

[image: possible desired]

Note if there is a better way to indicate row dependency, so non-literal answers may also work.